# Adding files with separate thread to my listbox like queue

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application, I want to add the option to add Wireshark files after selecting a root folder.

I am using this class to get all the files from the root folder (all the folders that I have permission to access):

```
public static class SafeFileEnumerator
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDirectories(string parentDirectory, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
    {
        try
        {
            var directories = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            {
                directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory).SelectMany(x => EnumerateDirectories(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
            }
            return directories.Concat(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(parentDirectory, searchPattern));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateFiles(string path, string searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
    {
        try
        {
            var dirFiles = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
            if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            {
                dirFiles = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).SelectMany(x => EnumerateFiles(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
            }
            return dirFiles.Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern));
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

and after click on Add directory button:

```
private void btnAddDir_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileToAdd = string.Empty;
    DialogResult dialog = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Editcap editcap = new Editcap();

        foreach (string fileName in SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            if (editcap.isWiresharkFormat(fileName))
            {
                if (editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileName))
                {
                    listBoxFiles.Items.Add(fileName);
                }
                else if (!editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileName))
                {
                    listBoxFiles.Items.Add(editcap.getNewFileName(fileName));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Editcap editcap = new Editcap();` - my class that checks if a file is a valid Wireshark file with 2 methods: `isWiresharkFormat` and `isLibpcapFormat`. `getNewFileName` - if the file is not a pcap file, it is converted to a pcap file.

What I want is to add all the correct files (Wireshark files) added to my list box in a different thread so the GUI is not blocked. Ideally after each file is found it would be added to my list box immediately, not waiting until all files are evaluated.

Comment: I strongly recommend to you the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach to your question which uses the `Reactive Extensions`.

First add the references to the RX libraries and the following `using` statement to your class definition:

```
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Concurrency;
```

Then, add an `IDisposable` private field which will be used to clean up any remaining thread work when you close the application and modify the `btnAddDir_Click_1` method like this:

```
IDisposable _disposable; 

private void btnAddDir_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string fileToAdd = string.Empty;
    DialogResult dialog = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Editcap editcap = new Editcap();

        var observable = SafeFileEnumerator.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .ToObservable()
            .SubscribeOn(NewThreadScheduler.Default);

        _disposable = observable.Subscribe((fileName) =>
            {
                if (editcap.isWiresharkFormat(fileName))
                {
                    if (editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileName))
                    {
                        listBoxFiles.Items.Add(fileName);
                    }
                    else if (!editcap.isLibpcapFormat(fileName))
                    {
                        listBoxFiles.Items.Add(editcap.getNewFileName(fileName));
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

In `YourForm.Designer.cs`, dispose properly the `_disposable` object:

```
/// <summary>
/// Clean up any resources being used.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
    }

    //dispose the observable IDisposable
    if (_disposable != null)
        _disposable.Dispose();

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: can i just define my thread as isBackground  = true instead of IDisposable to ensure that after close the application all my threads will close to ?

Comment: using System.Reactive.Linq; and using System.Reactive.Concurrency; not recognized ? i am using .net 4.0

Comment: You have to download and install the RX Framework. A simple way to do it in VS2012 is to right-click on your project, select **Manage NuGet Packages...**, search online for _Reactive_ and install the **Reactive Extensions - Main Library**.

Comment: Cross-thread operation not valid when try to add files to my listbox

Comment: 4.0, i put the problematic lines inside:                      this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                            {
                                listBoxFiles.Items.Add(fileName);
                            }); and now its ok, is it correct way to do it ?

Comment: its ok now but if i choose drive instead of folder for example D:\ this wont return all the files, only ~50, and when i choose my folder that contains all my files for example D:/dir i get all my files (more then 2000)

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use: `(new DirectoryInfo(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)).EnumerateFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` instead of your `SafeFileEnumerator`?

Comment: i try to use it but with SafeFileEnumerator i get only the files from location with permissions

Comment: after added your code the stop button doesn't work (close();) so the application cannot slose

Comment: I modified the last code snippet, i.e. checking `if (_disposable != null)`. Please update your code accordingly.